# Finding fields containing specific characters and quantities

Tags: mysql

I have a homework assignment where I have to find all the fields in a table containing 2 a's in them. I have been searching for hours. I am convinced I have to use wildcards but I continue to get fields containing more than 2 fields which is no acceptable. Please Help!!!

Comment: does the answer have to be pure mysql?

Comment: What do you mean, 'all the fields'? Do you mean return all the column names which have 2 a's? Or all the records in one column that have 2 a's?

Comment: Yes, it has to be pure mysql. Thanks for any Help!!!

Comment: All the records in one column that have 2 a's?

Comment: lynks, yes, it has to be pure mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  RLIKE:

```
WHERE my_field RLIKE "a{2}"
```